# Is it possible to use an iBeacon to get the UUIDs of devices in proximity?

Tags: ibeacon

Is it possible to use an iBeacon to get the UUIDs of all devices in its radius? I tried searching this up, but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: No, since a iBeacon only emits. But a custom device could listen to everything emitting around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, iBeacon is a standard designed for broadcast-only, meaning that it can only advertise data (UUID, Major, and Minor). However, there's nothing stopping you from building a device that's more than just iBeacon. Actually, most of the beacons available today are more than just iBeacon hardware, with connectivity mode and adjustable settings, which goes beyond what's specified in the iBeacon documentation.

A good example of a device like that is an iPhone. You can make your iPhone act as an iBeacon (at Estimote, we call this Virtual Beacon: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200908836-What-s-Virtual-Beacon-) and still have apps installed that are monitoring for other iBeacon regions.

Cheers.